# python comma separate values by thousands without trailing zeros

Tags: python, django, floating-point, number-formatting, decimal-point

I am trying to comma separate float amount by thousands. I am able to do that using the locale.format() function. But the expected output is not considering the decimal points.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
amount = locale.format('%d', 10025.87, True)
amount
'10,025'
```

My expected output should be 10,025.87, keeping the trailing values. Please let me know if something of this sort is possible

```
Value: 1067.00
Output: 1,067

Value: 1200450
Output: 1,200,450

Value: 1340.9
Output: 1,340.9
```

Comment: %d is an integer format code. Try using %f

Comment: Austin Hastings and manvi77, yes it works but it leaves an enormous amount of trailing zeros along with it. Had to use rstrip in combination to remove them. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
# strip any potential trailing zeros because %f is used.
amount = locale.format('%f', 10025.87, True).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
amount  # '10,025.87'
```

Comment: This one works but it does not remove the '.' Would need to do an additional '.rstrip('.')'. What I am doing right now is amount = locale.format('%f', 10025.00, True).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')

Comment: Yes. Updated my answer to remove trailing `.` in case only thousands exist.